# Simple Notes App Not Working With Local Storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a bare bones project that displays a list of notes and a button that will add a new note to that list to be displayed. My issue is that the new notes are not added/retrieved from local storage and I'm not sure what is causing it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
function App() {

  const [notesList, setNotesList] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const notesJSON = localStorage.getItem('ayo')
    if (notesJSON != null) setNotesList(JSON.parse(notesJSON))
    console.log(notesList)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('ayo', JSON.stringify(notesList))
  }, [notesList])

  function addNote(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const newNote = {
      id: Date.now() + Math.random(),
      text: 'this is a new note',
      status: false,
    }
    setNotesList([...notesList, newNote])
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      {notesList.map((note) => {
        return <h1 key={note.id}>{note.text}</h1>
      })}
      <form onSubmit={addNote}>
        <button type='submit'>Add Note</button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your first `useEffect` has no dependancy, therefore it's going to get triggered at every render, not sure that's what you want to do, since you might have conflciting behaviour between this `useEffect and the second one`

Comment: @Gregoire Ducharme I thought having a dependency of [] means it only runs when the page is loaded for the first time. I want my first use effect to get the previous notes from local storage and set that to notesList. I want the second use effect to update the local storage every time a new note is added.

Comment: You're right, `[]` is only triggered when mounting or unmounting. I got confused with no paramter at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the console log from the first `useEffect` where we retrieve data from `localStorage` and where we update `notesList` state if there is data previously stored in it. For logging purposes, add a button to check the data that is stored in the `localStorage` like [below](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-stitch-9v3g7d?file=/src/App.js).

We can'not watch the changes of `localStorage` by using `useEffect` with deps `notesList`. If you try, you will always get data that one step behind the `notesList` state value.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [notesList, setNotesList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const notesJSON = localStorage.getItem("ayo");
    notesJSON && setNotesList(JSON.parse(notesJSON));
  }, []);

  // this will always log the data that one step behind the notelist state
  useEffect(() => {
    const notesJSON = localStorage.getItem("ayo");
    notesList && console.log(JSON.parse(notesJSON));
  }, [notesList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (notesList.length > 0) {
      localStorage.setItem("ayo", JSON.stringify(notesList));
    }
  }, [notesList]);

  const addNote = useCallback(() => {
    const newNote = {
      id: Date.now() + Math.random(),
      text: "this is a new note",
      status: false,
    };
    setNotesList([...notesList, newNote]);
  }, [notesList]);

  const resetNote = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("ayo", JSON.stringify([]));
    setNotesList([]);
  };

  const logNote = () => {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("ayo"));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      {notesList.map((note) => {
        return (
          <div key={note.id}>
            <h1>{note.text}</h1>
            <p>{note.id}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={addNote}>Add Note</button>
      <button onClick={resetNote}>Reset Note</button>
      <button onClick={logNote}>Log Note</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I added the condition `if (notesList.length > 0)` in my code and the notes load. Conversely, if I remove the same condition from your code, it no longer loads. Why does not having this check break the code?

Comment: `if (notesList.length > 0)` will make sure the app will not reset the persisted data in localStorage with an empty array generated by `useState` at the initial render

Answer (score 0):

The second `useEffect` is unnecessary, you should set the appended list to your state and the storage in the `addNote` function and the first `useEffect` hook should be used to load your initial state and that's it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const [notesList, setNotesList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const notesJSON = localStorage.getItem("ayo");
    if (notesJSON != null) {
      setNotesList(JSON.parse(notesJSON));
    }
  }, []);

  function addNote(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newNote = {
      id: Date.now() + Math.random(),
      text: "this is a new note",
      status: false
    };
    const appendedList = [...notesList, newNote];

    setNotesList(appendedList);
    localStorage.setItem("ayo", JSON.stringify(appendedList));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      {notesList.map((note) => {
        return <h1 key={note.id}>{note.text}</h1>;
      })}
      <form onSubmit={addNote}>
        <button type="submit">Add Note</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I see that is is unnecessary, however, why does using my method with two useEffects cause the notes to not load?